# Reflection : Different behavior while using typeof() or IsAssignableFrom() to check interface implemented by a class

Tags: c#, .net, typeof, reflection

I have two interfaces `IConfigurationManager` and `ILocator` defined in the same assembly (lets call it assembly "A") and the same namespace.

There is a start-up project called "B" which has "project reference" to the assembly "A".

Assembly A contains concrete implementations of both the interfaces too. I have a "post-build event" on assembly A which copies DLL to the "B" project's 'bin\debug' folder from where application is run when i run it from visual studio 2012.

In the app.config file, I mention which assembly and type to use when I want concrete implementations of both the interfaces. (I need to resolve type mapping at run time and will have interfaces and implementations in different assemblies which I many not develope at all.)

In my code, I load assembly A (using `Assembly.LoadFile()`) from the 'bin\debug\' folder of the start-up project. Then I iterate through all types and check if a class is of type `ILocator` using this code:

```
if(type.GetInterfaces.Contains(typeof(IConfigurationManager))
```

This returns FALSE but on the other hand, similar code for the `ILocator` returns TRUE. **Why does this happen?** I tried to use `IsAsseignableFrom()` too, but I got the same result.

**Why one call succeeds and other fails when everything (like assembly in which interfaces declared, assembly from which type is loaded etc.) else is same while checking interfaces implemented by a class?**

Note: I am aware of the `Unity` container etc. But I still have the same question related to type checking using reflection.

Comment: what is typeof(<IConfigurationManagerImplemented>).GetInterfaces() output?

Comment: @zabulus: When I attach a debugger, I can clearly see the `IConfigurationManager` interface in the list returned by GetInterfaces(). However,  `if(type.GetInterfaces.Contains(typeof(IConfigurationManager))` returns false! .. But strangely, this is not the case with `ILocator` !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because the 'everything else' is not the same. Since your B project has a project reference to A, it ends up loading A twice: first by CLR, when B uses the type `ILocator` from A, and then when you explicitly load A with `LoadFile`. Because `LoadFile` loads assemblies into a different [binding context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx), you get two copies of A in your application domain, with two sets of types which (confusingly) have the same `FullName` etc. but are [nevertheless different](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FusionLoaderContextsUnableToCastObjectOfTypeWhateverToTypeWhatever.aspx). You may check this by comparing the `Assembly` objects in the `IConfigurationManager` from `type.GetInterfaces ()` (or `type` for that matter) and from `typeof (IConfigurationManager)`.

Comment: Thanks.. Many upvotes for stating "'everything else' is not the same" ! I used `Assembly.Load` instead of `LoadFile` and that solved the problem.